# Contradiction for $(dy/dx)^{-1}=dx/dy$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

So I have seen in the derivation of Euler chain Equation (i.e. $\displaystyle \frac{\partial x}{\partial y} \cdotp \frac{\partial y}{\partial z} \cdotp \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \ =\ -1$ )

where we use $\displaystyle \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} \ =\ \frac{1}{\partial x/\partial y}$

So, I have a contradiction.

Let's say $x = rcos(\theta)$ -------- (1)

and $y = rsin(\theta)$,
so we have $x^2+y^2=r^2$ ---------(2)

$\displaystyle \frac{\partial r}{\partial x} \ = cos(\theta)$ from eqn(2)

And $\displaystyle \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} \ = cos(\theta)$ from eqn(1).

Where is the problem?

If    $\displaystyle \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} \ =\ \frac{1}{\partial x/\partial y}$ is false, then what are the conditions where it's true?

Comment: If $x=r\cos \theta$ then $r=\frac x{\cos \theta}$ so $\frac {\partial r}{\partial x}=\frac 1{\cos \theta}$.

Comment: Not sure if a duplicate, but this is closely related to [Sufficient conditions for partial derivative reciprocal](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4125401/26369).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you have functions of two variables, and when there is ambiguity, you have to indicate which variable is fixed when you compute a partial derivative.

For example, you can fix $\theta$ when you derive $x=r\cos\theta$ and get
$\displaystyle \Big( \frac{\partial r}{\partial x} \Big)_\theta\ = \frac{1}{cos(\theta)}.$

Or you can fix $y$ when you derive $x^2+y^2=r^2$ and get $\displaystyle 2x  \Big(\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} \Big)_y = 2r$, so
$\displaystyle \Big(\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} \Big)_y = \frac{r}{x} = \frac{1}{cos(\theta)}.$